# Twitter bot - Replying to specific users using Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to write my first twitter bot, and what I specifically want it to do is to reply when a specific user tweets something. Instead of searching for every user that mentions the word 'taco' I want to only search for when a small list of people mention 'taco'. For example, my bot only looks for tweets from Bob and Sue that mention 'taco', but not tweets from Fred. I'm not finding what I need.

Comment: You have to show us your code.

Answer (score 1):

From the [`Tweepy`](http://tweepy.readthedocs.org/en/v3.5.0/index.html) documentation, you should probably use the method [`API.user_timeline`](http://tweepy.readthedocs.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html#API.user_timeline) to read a specific user tweets.

> **API.user_timeline([user_id/screen_name])**
>
> Returns the 20 most recent statuses posted from the
> authenticating user or the *user specified*.
>
> *Parameters*:
> **user_id** – Specifies the ID of the user
> **screen_name** – Specifies the screen name of the user

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish this through the [user timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline) API endpoint; however, depending on how many terms and users you want to track, you'd have to worry about rate limits (the user timeline endpoint rate limit is pretty high, 300/app auth/15 mins, 150/user auth/15 mins = 450/15 mins), and also the fact that you'd have to call the endpoint manually at some time interval.

Another way to do this is by using the streaming API endpoint, specifically the [user stream](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/userstreams).  Follow everyone you want to reply to, and then create some rules for specific phrases.  As followed users post tweets, they should stream to your user stream endpoint.  You'd just have to have a listener running, with some logic for tracked users/phrases.

```
track = {
    'taco': ['Bob', 'Sue'],
    'salsa': ['John', 'Steve'],
    'guacamole': ['Mary', 'Fred']
}
```

You'd subclass Tweepy's `StreamListener`:

```
class TacoListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
        # Note, I rolled my own Twitter API wrapper, and just had a glance at the Tweepy docs, so some of this syntax might be incorrect, change it as required
        # I think Tweepy has syntax like: status.text; I'll just refer to the fields as they appear in the Twitter JSON payload
        for k, v in track.items():
            if k in status.get('text') and status.get('screen_name') in v:
                tweet = ""
                for name in v:
                    tweet += "@" + name
                tweet += " are talking about " + k + "!  Yum."
                api.update_status(status=tweet)
```